# Websockets don't receive data

Tags: java, python, websocket

For a school project I have to make a raspberry pi send sensor data to a java application using websockets. The raspberry pi has the websocket server and a client script running. Both those scripts are python. I have managed to get the server and the java and python client working the problem i am having is that when i send data it will only receive its own data. So when the python script sends data the server, the server prints the data and sends it back to the python client and the python client prints it. When the java client sends data the server, the server prints the data and it sends it back to the java app and the java app prints it but the python script doesn't print the data.
What am i doing wrong?

Server.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)
        await websocket.send(message)

start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Client.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        
        await websocket.send(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        while (True):
            # Dit ontvangt een bericht van de server en print het 
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(msg)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

ExampleClient.java

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

/**
 * This example demonstrates how to create a websocket connection to a server. Only the most
 * important callbacks are overloaded.
 */
public class ExampleClient extends WebSocketClient {

  public ExampleClient(URI serverUri, Draft draft) {
    super(serverUri, draft);
  }

  public ExampleClient(URI serverURI) {
    super(serverURI);
  }

  public ExampleClient(URI serverUri, Map<String, String> httpHeaders) {
    super(serverUri, httpHeaders);
  }

  @Override
  public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
        send("Hello, it is me. Mario :)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("received: " + message);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    // The codecodes are documented in class org.java_websocket.framing.CloseFrame
    System.out.println(
        "Connection closed by " + (remote ? "remote peer" : "us") + " Code: " + code + " Reason: "
            + reason);
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // if the error is fatal then onClose will be called additionally
  }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        ExampleClient c = new ExampleClient(new URI(
                "ws://localhost:8765")); // more about drafts here: http://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki/Drafts
        c.connect();
    }
}
```

(For testing all the scripts are run on the same computer)

Comment: You should maintain a list of all connected clients and send message to all of them.

Comment: When you say "but the python script doesn't print the data" you talking about python client or python server?